# JQuery .blur not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to (server-)validate an input field when it loses its focus. But nothing happens when the input field loses its focus, alert is not triggered.

My code, php-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Origin: *');?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="smicadminjavascripts.js"></script> 

        <title>Service Management In the Cloud - Administration</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="adminmenu">
            <a id="agents" class="adminmenu_items">Agenter</a></br>
            <a id="customer" class="adminmenu_items">Kunder</a></br> 
            <a id="misc" class="adminmenu_items">&Ouml;vrigt</a></br> 

        </div>
        <div id="adminarea">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Upon loading the side, I will add the form to the  div id="adminarea"

Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       

    $("#username_ID").blur(function(data){
            alert("BLUR"); 
    });

    $.get("registeraccount.php", function(data){
         $("#adminarea").html(data);
    });               

            $("#registerform").live("submit", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                $.post("registeraccount.php",$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

                alert(msg);
        });
       });

  });
```

Other scripts in the .ready function works properly.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: try focusing first, and then bluring it..

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/sGXqL/

Comment: Do you mean like: $("#username_ID").focus(function(data){}? No difference. Not triggered.

Comment: Works ok but your BRs are wrong, you have to append the closing slash after the BR characters, or don't close it at all.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other element with id username_ID?

Comment: @Juhana, yes, searched for it. No other id username_ID.

Comment: Genesis, yes. Kind of the same as @Tomgrohl. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the post with the entire file.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right file? You're not even including jQuery.

Comment: sorry...it's true. No, it's not. I will update the answer...

Comment: The live site is exactly the same as you show here, and it still doesn't include jQuery.

Comment: Updated the post with the real files. Not going to extrat only the "important" information next time, but all.

Comment: It's a good idea to narrow down the problem to the smallest possible code, but then *you have to make sure the extract will show the problem* before asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ca2bb.php

- Click on username
- Get back to my post
- Alert fired!

For your problem:

Include jquery :)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Updated the post with the entire file.

Comment: you forgot to include jquery library

Comment: Actually, it's included. The file I added was just an extraction, not going to do like that again... The form is loaded dynamically into the web page. Does that matter?

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.focusout()` and don't forget to include jquery library.